# ADO CreateParameter fails with 0x800A0D5D when attempting to write to Oracle's RAW(16) field from C++

Tags: c++, oracle, ado, guid

I am attempting to write a Guid into a RAW(16) field in Oracle using a parameterized SQL query.

Having previously read the RAW(16), it comes off the database as a variant array of bytes (type VT_ARRAY | VT_UI1).  Therefore I am now attempting to write back a value as an array of bytes.

My variant is set to VT_ARRAY | VT_UI1 again, and CreateParameter is called with adUnsignedTinyInt | adArray.

Unfortunately this throws the 0X800A0D5D code.

I have also tried writing the parameter using "HEXTORAW('0000000000000000')" as a BSTR parameter, using adBSTR in the call to CreateParameter.  This time CreateParameter succeeded, but the call Execute on the _ADODB::CommandPtr then threw an error.

Please could someone guide me as to how I should write a Guid into Oracle's RAW(16) using a parameterized SQL query (ideally using ADO through C++)?

Comment: Do you need to generate the GUID within C++, i.e. could you let the database do it for you?

Comment: Yeah @Ben, the GUID has to be generated within C++.

Comment: Looking at this link (http://www.w3schools.com/ado/ado_datatypes.asp), I should use the 'adBinary' datatype for CreateParameter to update Oracle's Raw fields.  I might try that next.  Does anyone know how I would populate the variant as a binary parameter?

Comment: PLEASE NOTE, I must report that I did find another issue in my code that could have been responsible for the attempt to use 'HEXTORAW()' in the string parameter failing.  If I had the time, I would retest, but as it is I'm happy that I've got it to work using binary data - see my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have got this to work using VT_ARRAY | VT_UI1 in my variant, passing adBinary as the data-type to CreateParameter.

There is also a chance (from other things I've read) that Oracle would be happy with a plain BSTR parameter containing just the binary data in HEX notation.